# How to get list of array keys with null values?

Tags: php, arrays, null, key

I have an array. How can I get a list of the keys that have null values? Is there some short way to find them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) has an optional search_value parameter, so you can just put:

```
array_keys($array, null, true);
```

You must set the third parameter (strict comparison) to true for it to match only nulls.

Comment: Thanks! This is the kind of answer I was looking for. Very educational!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the function that I came up with:

```
function find_nulls($a) {
    return array_keys(array_filter($a, function($b) {
       return is_null($b);
    }) );
}
```

It seems to work as desired.